# 8 pin Mini-DIN to USB converter; where can I buy one?

Tags: keyboards, old-hardware-adaptation, usb

I have a vintage Sun Microsystems Type 6 keyboard that uses an 8 pin Mini-DIN and I want to use it on a modern computer with at least a USB 2.0 port. I've searched online e-commerce websites but most sell only PS/2 6 pin to USB adpatpers or converters. One site (Drakware) sells what I'm looking for but is unavailable (https://www.drakware.com/shop/p/sun2usb) and still awaiting a response from them. Here are photos for reference:
[image: Sun type 6 keyboard]

[image: 8 pin Mini-DIN]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: drakware has closed up their shop for now. An option might be to homebrew something with an Arduino Micro, such as [SunType5_ArduinoAdapter](https://github.com/benr/SunType5_ArduinoAdapter) or [suniversal](https://github.com/xelalexv/suniversal). And watch out for that bent pin in your mini-DIN cable!

Comment: I’ve had some success using a propelling pencil to straighten bent pins.

Comment: Beware of the power button on the top right.  One of our customers pressed it and it shut down the Sun workstation.  Took us a week to figure out how to disable it.  Hopefully that is not enabled when you connect it to your machine.

Comment: @scruss thanks for the info. I guessed as much, drakware products are all sold-out. Time to take out the soldering kits..

Comment: @Frog: or tweezers wrapped in some non-insulating material.

Comment: @cup: thanks for the heads-up; will keep that in mind.

Comment: It seems the verdict at <https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/> was that questions about where to obtain parts are off-topic, so…

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe solve the 2-step conversion in 2 separate steps: Belkin used to offer a Sun keyboard/mouse to PS/2 [adapter](https://www.belkin.com/support/dl/f1d082.pdf) as part of their KVM product line (these adapters seem to be available fairly cheaply [from eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/270893720308?hash=item3f128622f4:g:1MMAAOSwAuZX5EdI) ). Once you have a standard PS/2 connectpr, converting that to USB should be possible with standard adapters for PCs.

Comment: Don't those standard adapters work only if the keyboard supports both PS/2 and USB protocols, and adapts accordingly?  (I suppose that to mean PS/2 signalling over USB wires).   Would the Sun adapter support that?

Comment: @another-dave There are active PS/2 to USB adapters that do protocol conversion, as well as passive ones that just swap the wires around. See, for example, https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/how-can-i-connect-a-din-plug-keyboard-to-usb/

Comment: @another-dave Direction is of importance here: There's no PS/2 (keyboard) to USB (Computer) adapters like that. The adapters you refer to are USB (Keyboard) to PS/2 (Computer) that will only work with keyboards that support both protocols. There are no computers to my knowledge that would support both PS/2 and USB on a PS/2 socket (but there are keyboards that do, the Sun one is none of them). The direction PS/2 (KB) to USB (Computer) is always an active converter. Unfortunately, the Sun keyboards aren't PS/2 (at least not the PS/2 a normal PC would assume), so we first need to go there

Comment: The PS/2 6pin mini-DIN (keyboard) to USB (computer) active converter is pretty straightforward; i'm typing on the setup right now. This 8-pin Sun keyboard is definitely going to need an active converter to USB. Problem is the vendor. I'd like to avoid going through an arduino setup if I can.